# Pagination with multiple GET values doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, get, pagination

I have the url to my blog page:
`www.something.com/index.php?menuid=6` or just `www.something.com/?menuid=6`

I would like to add a GET variable (the page number, because there are too much posts to display them on one page) to the current url, like this:
`www.something.com/index.php?id=6&page=12` or `www.something.com/?id=6&page=12`

What should i write in the `<a href>` of the pagination if I don't know the www.something.com and the value of the menuid?

I tried this:

```
$pagination = "<p>";
$pagination.= ($page <= 1) ? "First | " : "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}&page=1\">First</a> | ";
$pagination.= ($page <= 1) ? "Previous | " : "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}&page=".($page-1)."\">Previous</a> | ";

for ($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) {
    $pagination.= ($page == $i) ? "{$i} | " : "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}&page={$i}\">{$i}</a> | ";
}

$pagination.= ($page >= $pages) ? "Next | " : "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}&page=".($page+1)."\">Next</a> | ";
$pagination.= ($page >= $pages) ? "Last" : "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}&page={$pages}\">Last</a>";
$pagination.= "</p>\n";
```

but when i clicked on the 2nd page and then the 3rd page, the result was this:

```
index.php?menuid=6&page=2&page=3
```

My other question is, that how to show just the previous two and the next two page numbers [like in this one](http://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ci-pagination-02.png)?

This is the php code for the pagination:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");
$howmuch = 5;
$total = mysql_num_rows($query); 
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$pages = ceil($total/$howmuch);
$where = ($page-1)*$howmuch; 

$active="(SELECT s_id FROM status WHERE s_name='active')";
$sql = "SELECT post_id, post_title, post_content, post_date
        FROM posts
        WHERE post_s_id=".$active."
        ORDER BY post_id DESC
        LIMIT {$where}, {$howmuch}";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$output="";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$output.="Here are the posts";
}
return $output.$pagination;
```

!!!UPDATE!!!
I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention, that the posts.php is included in the index.php, and the above code is in the posts.php. 
 
The menu_id is in the code of the index.php, not in the posts.php, but the url is the same.

Comment: Instead of concatenating the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] each time, you need to find the $page=2 substring and replace the 2 with the next page number.

Comment: You could use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] instead of REQUEST_URI and add the menuid yourself.

Comment: You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) for extraction path before question mark, $_GET for GET params and [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query) for composing urls.

Comment: @Petra How to add the menuid if i don't know the value?

Comment: @darksoul90 Try it with $_GET['menuid'] - it makes no difference with the include - besides there are functions used.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will get everything in the URL, thats why it's adding up all your page vars.

Use

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?menuid='.$_GET['menuid'].'&page='.$page
```

Comment: The problem is, that the menuid belongs to te index.php,not the posts.php

Comment: And you can't add it in the href for the posts page like this `<a href="posts.php?menuid=<?php echo $_GET['menuid'] ?>">Posts</a>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick function to generate this regardless of the parameters in the url

```
function getPageUri($page) {
    $_GET['page'] = $page;
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value ) {
        $query_string[] = "$key=$value";
    }
    return $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?' . implode('&', $query_string);
}
```

Comment: That's great! But how to use it?

Comment: add it to the top of your php and use $link = getPageUri(1); for page 1 getPageUri(2) for page 2 etc etc